# Handling errors when querying computer accounts

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im using [this script](http://blog.mikewalker.me/2013/04/retrieve-ou-for-computer.html) to retrieve the OU for a list of computers. When a computer doesn't exist, I get an error:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\tools\scripts\get-OU5.ps1:35 char:5
+     $dn = $result.Properties["distinguishedName"]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

When I manually searched for the computer on the domain, it didn't exist. Also, after the error occurs, it lists the previous OU value it received from the last computer, as the result for this computer that gives the error.

I know there are error handling abilities in PowerShell, but I'm just not sure on where to put the error handling and then also report it as the result in the output.

Comment: If you have the ActiveDirectory Module you could accomplish all of that in one line.  Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select DistinguishedName.  If you want to edit his script, it's likely $result is $null at line 35.  so try changing to if ((!$?) -or (-not $result)  { return }

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following script to retrieve the information. It uses the built-in error handling capabilities in PowerShell:

```
function Get-ComputerProperties{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    #requires -version 3
    param(
        [parameter(ParameterSetName = "ComputerName", Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        $ComputerName
    )

    begin{
        Import-Module ActiveDirectory

        function Get-ADParent ([string] $dn) {
            $parts = $dn -split '(?<![\\]),'
            $parts[1..$($parts.Count-1)] -join ','
        }

    }
    process {
        $result = $Null
        try{
            $result = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $ComputerName} -ErrorAction Stop
            if($result){
                New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Name" = $ComputerName; "OU" = (Get-ADParent $result.DistinguishedName)}
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Error while retrieving Computer properties for ComputerName $Computername ($($_.Exception.Message))"
        }

    }

    end{
        Remove-Module ActiveDirectory
    }
}
```

You can use the script in the following way:

```
Get-ComputerProperties -ComputerName "Computer1"
```

or

```
"Computer1","Computer2" | Get-ComputerProperties
```

or with a text file:

```
Get-Content "C:\computers.txt" | %{ Get-ComputerProperties }
```

Comment: is it possible this one can be used with a computer list? i have probably 100 servers to check.

Comment: Of course, I've added that possibility to my answer.